vscode disassembly view displays nothing but ?? bytes
I am trying to debug my c++ program running on bochs by vscode. However, when I try to open the disassembly view, it displays nothing but ?? bytes.

However, I am able to see the disassembly codes by command "-exec disassemble /m"

This is my launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:1234",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/program/objs/showStack.exe",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "preLaunchTask": "OOS run"
    }
  ]
}

and tasks.json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "OOS make",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "all",
                "-C",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src"
            ],
            "detail": "Make OOS",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "OOS run",
            "command": "bochs.exe",
            "args": [
                "-q",
                "-f",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\targets\\UNIXV6++\\bochsrc.bxrc",
                "-noconsole"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\targets\\UNIXV6++\\",
                "env": {
                    "BXSHARE": "D:\\unix V6++V1\\Bochs-2.6",
                    "Path": "${env:Path};D:\\unix V6++V1\\Bochs-2.6\\"
                }
            },
            "detail": "run OOS",
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "isBackground": true
        },
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

How can I fix the problem?
